# AWS multiple lambdas with same CodeUri

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have multiple lambdas in my AWS serverless project and they all have the same `CodeUri` which is a folder in my project. For example, they all point to `src/`.

In the basic usage, or at least how I use it, the `sam build` option create a folder for each lambda. All of the folders contain the same code. Then, when running `sam deploy` each zip is uploaded to S3. The zips are all the same and it takes a lot of redundent time to upload them all.

Is there an option "to tell" sam to upload it only once?

I saw that I can build the zip manually, then uploading it to S3. How can I then set the uri in the `CodeUri` of the lambdas? Should I do it using external parameter or there is dedicated way to signal it?

Thank you

Comment: My biggest question here would be, do you need to have them all in the same folder? A simple folder per lambda here will save you a lot of pain, also make everything more organised. Is there anything stopping you from doing this?

Comment: They all share the same package

Comment: You can use Lambda layers for shared packages.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: You can see in my answer that I did use layers. The problem is that the lambda is in the package hence it upload all the project all over again. Hence you must move it to temporary file as I did.

Comment: Please see this question related to the new problem of constant re-uploading : [How to avoid AWS SAM rebuild and reupload a gradle function with unchanged code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159975/794088)

Answer (score 4):

After hard effort, using David Conde's idea, I managed to find some solution for it. What we want to achieve is uploading the lambda's zip (with all of it's dependencies) once and point all the lambdas to use this zip.

This process is seperated into couple of steps which I'll try to describe in much
details as I can. Some of them might not be relevant exactly for your case.

## General idea

The general idea is to create a layer which contains the code we want to upload once. Then, for each lambda, specify it uses this layer. Each lambda will have it handler points to somewhere in the source directory. Hence, running code "from the layer". But! we must specify code for the lambda to run/attach a zip - even if it's not what going to run. To skip that, we are going to attach it an "empty" code.

## Build folder

First, create a build folder where we are going to work, for example: `mkdir -p .build/`

In addition, define the following variables:

- `s3_bucket="aaaaaaaa"`
- `s3_prefix="aaaaaaaa"`
- `s3_lambda_zip_suffix="$s3_prefix/lambda.zip"`
- `s3_lambda_zip="s3://$s3_bucket/$s3_lambda_zip_suffix"`

## Creating the source zip

When lambda is unzipped, it's content is written to the working directory. When a layer is unzipped, it is unzipped into `/opt` as documented in AWS. Because our lambda needs to find our source code, which is "a depndencie" it needs to find it under `/opt`. To achieve it, we need it to be unzipped into `/opt/python`. We can do that by zipping `python/...` into a zip file.

First, we create the folder we will install the dependencies into the python folder:

- `mkdir -p .build/lambda_zip/python`
- `pip3 install -q --target .build/lambda_zip/python -r requirements.txt`

Then we zip it:

- `pushd .build/lambda_zip/ > /dev/null`
- `zip --quiet -r ./lambda.zip ./python`
- `popd > /dev/null`

Now, you probably want to add your src direcory:

- `zip --quiet -r .build/lambda_zip/lambda.zip src`

#Uploading to S3
Now, we have to upload the zip into S3 for our lambdas to load it.

- `aws s3 cp ".build/lambda_zip/lambda.zip" $s3_lambda_zip_path`

## Adding layer to `template.yaml`

Now, we need to add the layer into our `template.yaml` file, you can copy the following code after you read at AWS documentation:

```
Parameters:
  LambdaCodeUriBucket:
    Type: String
  LambdaCodeUriKey:
    Type: String

Resources:

  OnUpHealthLayer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      CompatibleRuntimes:
      - python3.8
      Content:
        S3Bucket: !Sub '${LambdaCodeUriBucket}'
        S3Key: !Sub '${LambdaCodeUriKey}'
```

## Create empty zip for the lambdas

Cloudformation must upload zip for lambdas, so we want it to create an empty zip. But it scans the dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file in the directory the same as the one of `template.yaml`. And we want it to upload something empty. Hence it must be in another folder.
To solve it, I copy the `template.yaml` to an empty directory and add empty `requirements.txt` file. After that, we can run `sam build` and `sam deploy` as usuall. Notice that we must pass it `LambdaCodeUriBucket` and `LambdaCodeUriKey`:

```
#create "empty" environment for the template to be built in
mkdir -p .build/empty_template
cp template.yaml .build/empty_template
pushd .build/empty_template > /dev/null
touch requirements.txt
sam build --template template.yaml
sam deploy \
    --template-file .aws-sam/build/template.yaml \
    --capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" \
    --region $region \
    --s3-bucket $s3_bucket \
    --s3-prefix $s3_prefix \
    --stack-name $stack_name \
    --parameter-overrides LambdaCodeUriBucket=$s3_bucket LambdaCodeUriKey=$s3_lambda_zip_suffix
popd > /dev/null
```

Notice that although we copied the template.yaml and called `sam build` on the new one, we already uploaded to s3 the zip file.

Important thing you must do is specify `.` as the `CodeUri` for your lambdas. Because they now use the "empty zip".

In the future, we will be able to do:

```
InlineCode: |
    def handler(event, context):
        pass
```

And not specify folder `.`.

But, currently `sam` doesn't support inline code for `python3.8` hence we use `.`. Anyway you will have to move it to seperate folder to remove it's dependencies.

Comment: Great explaination. TY

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I used SAM to deploy 23 Nodejs Lambda and I didn't have to go thru all the process above. When I build/deploy the app, the only "big" file is the node_modules layer and all lambda's code are sent separately. So, once the layer is send (~18M), all 23 files are sent in less then 30 sec. Here's my layout:

**template.yaml**

```
LambdaLayer:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
  Properties:
    LayerName: my-lambda-layer
    ContentUri: lib/.
    CompatibleRuntimes:
      - nodejs18.x
```

and each function reference this layer...

```
getVisitsFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: lambda.handler
    CodeUri: src/handlers/manage-visits
    Layers:
      - !Ref LambdaLayer
```

Now, my project structure looks like this :

```
.
├── ...
├── lib
│   └── nodejs
│       └── node18
│           ├── node_modules
│           │   ├── (all nodes modules code is here)
│           ├── package.json
│           └── package-lock.json
├── src
│   └── handlers
│       ├── manage-visits
│       │   ├── lambda.js
│       └── manage-visits-admin (others functions is the same pattern)
│           └── lambda.js
└── template.yml
```

So, the /lib is setup as AWS describe it in this doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html).
This is where everything there is gonna be package as the common layer for all my functions.

Then each function got is own subdir with a lambda.js that export my "handler" entrypoint:

```
const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
...
}
module.exports = { handler };
```

And that's it. When I run "sam deploy", the layer get build and sent with each individual package for each function. The extra benefit you get is that your code is available in the editor since the code base is very small (here's 14k):

[image]

P.S: This setup also work if you run locally with the "sam local start-api" but it's a little bit slower than deploy in AWS because each time you call a function, it build the image.

```
2023-10-06 22:09:46 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2023 22:09:46] "GET /journal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Invoking lambda.handler (nodejs18.x)                                                                                
LambdaLayer is a local Layer in the template                                                                     
Building image.....................
Using local image: samcli/lambda-nodejs:18-x86_64-73ce3f030935c3b2ab8326e01.                                        
                                                                                                                    
Mounting /home/user/project/backend/.aws-sam/build/manageJournalFunction as                     
/var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container                                                                    
START RequestId: 634376b0-2382-40fd-8223-3ce75ea24796 Version: $LATEST
```