# How to avoid AWS SAM rebuild and reupload a gradle function with unchanged code?

Tags: gradle, aws-lambda, micronaut, aws-sam

I'm developing an application with micronaut using SAM CLI to deploy it on AWS Lambda. As I was including dependencies and developing new features, the function packages got bigger an bigger (now they are around 250MB). This makes deployment take a while.

On top of that every time I edit `template.yaml` and then run `sam build && sam deploy` to try a new configuration on S3, RDS, etc... I have to wait for gradle to build the function again (even though it's unchanged since the last deployment) and upload the whole package to S3.

As I'm trying to configure this application with many trials and errors on SAM, waiting for this process to complete just to get an error because of some misconfiguration is getting quite counterproductive.

Also my SAM s3 bcuket is at 10GB size after just a single day of work. This may get expensive on the long run.

Is there a way to avoid those gradle rebuilds and reuploads when teh function code is unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **only updating the template.yml file**, you could copy the new version to `./.aws-sam/build folder` and then run `sam deploy`

```
$ cp template.yml ./.aws-sam/build/template.yml
$ sam deploy
```

If you are **editing a lambda** you could try to update the function code by itself (after you create it in the template and deploy of course). That can be done via the AWS CLI [update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) command:

```
rm index.zip 
cd lambda 
zip –X –r ../index.zip *
cd .. 
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name MyLambdaFunction --zip-file fileb://index.zip
```

more info can be found here:

- [Alexa Blogs - Publishing Your Skill Code to Lambda via the Command Line Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1UE9W1NQ0GYII/Publishing-Your-Skill-Code-to-Lambda-via-the-Command-Line-Interface)
- [AWS CLI Command Reference - lambda - update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html)

> my SAM s3 bcuket is at 10GB size

Heh. Yea start deleting stuff. Maybe you can write a script using [`aws s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)?

Comment: I did this a lot so I know it works. I am also impatient.

Comment: Its a good question. Thought a lot about it myself a few months ago.

Comment: About the script to cleanup the storage - https://github.com/epsagon/clear-lambda-storage